# How to create a two dimensional array of two dimensional arrays?

Tags: arrays, delphi, multidimensional-array

I it possible to create a two dimensional array of two dimensional arrays in Delphi; and if so how do you access the addresses in it?

My aim is to create something similar to a sudoku grid where you have smaller grids inside of a bigger one.

It would work much better in stead of ex. Declaring multiple 2D arrays of the same type or one big array.

Comment: On a side note, I don't know what you'd be using this for, but lets say you want to make a map with zooming. The more you zoom in, the finer the detail becomes, thus the smaller the grid lines are. Kinda like Google Maps/Earth. In this case, there isn't a grid within a grid, but rather a single scalable grid using, for example, a double type for Longitude/Latitude. Not sure if this may help depending on your intention.

Comment: @Jerry We know what it is used for, Sudoku

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like

```
type
  TSmallGrid = array[1..3, 1..3] of Integer;
  TBigGrid = array[1..3, 1..3] of TSmallGrid;
```

should work. Access to `BigArray: TBigGrid` would be with standard Pascal array syntax:

```
  MyInt := BigArray[1, 2, 1, 2]; // or even BigArray[1, 2][1, 2] to emphasize the nesting
```

or

```
  SmallArray := BigArray[1, 2];
```

Comment: Actually, if you want to emphasize that these are nested twodimensional arrays, you can also do `MyInt := BigArray[1, 2][1, 2];`.;

Comment: Thanks, @Rudy, integrated.