# How to create and access record members (converted from C# struct) of a multidimensional array in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, multidimensional-array, struct, record, pascal

My Struct in C#:

```
  private enum AlignEx
        {
            left,
            middle,
            right
        }
           
   private struct myStruct
        {
            public int index;
            public AlignEx alignment;
        }


private myStruct[,] ....... {

}
```

Now I have declared Structure as Record in Delphi like this:

```
 type
    AlignEx = (left, middle, right);

  type
    myStruct = record
      index: Integer;
      alignment: AlignEx ;

    end;
```

Now I am unable to get comma separated array of my struct like the C# one `myStruct[,]`

How do I implement that?

Thank you <3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a two dimensional array of two dimensional arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36080832/how-to-create-a-two-dimensional-array-of-two-dimensional-arrays)

Comment: [Pascal - Multi-dimensional Array](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pascal/pascal_multi_dimensional_arrays.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it:

```
type
    TAlignEx = (aeLeft, aeMiddle, aeRight);

    TMyStruct = record
      Index     : Integer;
      Alignment : TAlignEx;
    end;

const
    MyStructArray : array [0..2, 0..1] of TMyStruct =
        (((Index: 1; Alignment: aeLeft),
          (Index: 2; Alignment: aeLeft)),

         ((Index: 3; Alignment: aeMiddle),
          (Index: 4; Alignment: aeMiddle)),

         ((Index: 5; Alignment: aeRight),
          (Index: 6; Alignment: aeRight)));
```

I used a naming convention more usual in Delphi. It is generally a good idea to follow usual naming convention but of course you are free to use whatever you like most.